# I can't figure out why JS isn't collecting the user input

Tags: user-input

I am trying to write a simple Regex Checker  function that takes the user input and checks it against certain criteria. Only problem is, I can't get the user input to be passed into the new variable to begin the checking.

Can someone help me understand why I'm not seeing the user input in the log? I just want to be able to see the user input in the console so I can continue writing the code I need. EDIT-I know it is set to ALERT at the moment and not console.log-

```js
let first = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
let last = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

function regexChecker () {
    alert(first + last);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Regex Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='form'>
        <h2>Please enter your first and last name</h2>
        <label for='firstName'>First Name: </label>
        <input type='text' id='firstName'>
        <label for='lastName'>Last Name: </label>
        <input type='text' id='lastName' >
        <button onclick='regexChecker()' type='reset'>Verify Input</button>
    </form>
    <script src='./script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>a
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're reading the input field values before your method is ever invoked. Move your variable assignment inside your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign values of first and last inside the function cause these two lines invoke when the page loads so have null or empty string values. You must reassign them.

```js
function regexChecker () {
    let first = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    let last = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

    alert(first + last);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Regex Checker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='form'>
        <h2>Please enter your first and last name</h2>
        <label for='firstName'>First Name: </label>
        <input type='text' id='firstName'>
        <label for='lastName'>Last Name: </label>
        <input type='text' id='lastName' >
        <button onclick='regexChecker()' type='reset'>Verify Input</button>
    </form>
    <script src='./script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>a
```

Comment: Your welcome. and also check as correct answer so other users with same problem use it.